# How to remove these darn Buttons from Yahoo Media Player?

Tags: jquery, media-player, yahoo

I have Yahoo Media Player on my site, which pops up for mp3 files when linked, but the play/pause button will not go away EVER!  I have tried, CSS, and even jQuery to attempt to remove it, but it doesn't work.  How can I get rid of the buttons associated with all links on the page via the Yahoo Web Player.

It's only 14x14 pixels, and is too small, but I can't even resize it either.  Here's what it looks like:

[image]

But really, I just want it to go away completely!

Have this in the Head Tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">var YWPParams = { autoadvance: false };</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://webplayer.yahooapis.com/player-beta.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    /* Yahoo! Media Player: Hide play/pause button */
    a.ymp-btn-page-play,
    a.ymp-btn-page-pause, ywp-page-btn {
      margin-left:-20px !important;
    }

    a.ymp-btn-page-play em.ymp-skin,
    a.ymp-btn-page-pause em.ymp-skin, ywp-page-btn {
      display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Code I have tried, but didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ywp-page-btn").css({backgroundImage: 'none', 'display': 'none', 'height': 0, 'width': 0, maxWidth: 0, minWidth: 0 });
});

$(window).load(function(){
    $(".ywp-page-btn").css({backgroundImage: 'none', 'display': 'none', 'height': 0, 'width': 0, maxWidth: 0, minWidth: 0 });
});

$(window).bind("resize", function(){
    $(".ywp-page-btn").css({backgroundImage: 'none', 'display': 'none', 'height': 0, 'width': 0, maxWidth: 0, minWidth: 0 });
}).trigger("resize");
```

I even tried `.remove()` and that didn't work either.

I am using the following links within the body:

```
<a href="http://www.opportunityfinance.net/conference-2013/mp3/July9StayingConnectedCall.mp3" title="Staying Connected Call - July 9">July 9</a> and <a href="http://www.opportunityfinance.net/conference-2013/mp3/July17StayingConnectedCall.mp3" title="Staying Connected Call - July 17">July 17</a>
```

How do I get rid of this button, just want the link itself to open up the player. Or if I can resize the button to the actual size of the text that would be ok also.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, got it working with `.remove()` by adding a `setInterval(functionToCheckForExistence, 500);`

Than within the function that checks if it exists, if it does it removes it, if not, than it clears the Interval.

Works great now!

Arggg, doesn't work in Firefox on Windows 7 (Tested and still shows)... arggg!

Comment: Ok, my answer isn't exactly bulletproof unfortunately, because I just now tested in Firefox and the buttons still show... arggg!  Even with a Timer set to `.remove()` them.  How is this possible?